# variable already defined?

Tags: java, netbeans

While learning how tpass parameters i have run into an issue where i am unable to figure at why the program is displaying error. I'll highlight the code below.

```
public class pkgExone 
{
    static void displayMarkRange(int[] ref,double[] mark, double size,double topValue,
    double bottomValue, String message)
        {
            int index; //declare a variable index
              System.out.println("\n\n"+ message+"\n\n"); //print parameter message
                System.out.println("Reference \t Mark ");
                  System.out.println("Number \t Obtained\n");
                   // loop through the whole array and decide whether to print a students mark
        for(index=0;index<=size-1;index=index+1)
            {
              if ((mark[index]>= bottomValue) && (mark[index]<=topValue))
                {
                 System.out.println( ref[index]+" \t\t\t"+ mark[index]);
                } // end if construct
            } // end for loop
            System.out.println("\n\n");
        } // end of displayMarkRangeMethod

    static double Calaverage(double [] mark, double size)
    {
        int index;
        double total=0;
        double calculatedaverage;        
        int validentries=0;

        for (index=0;index<=size-1;index ++)

          if ((mark[index]>=1) && (mark [index] <=100))
           {
           **double total + mark [index];
           int validentries= validentries +1;**
           }
        **double calculatedaverage = total/validentires;**
        return calculatedaverage;


    }



    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double [] ref; 
        double Averagemark;
        double howMany=10;
        int[] studentID = {900,901,902,903,904,905,906,907,908,909};
        double[] examMark = {23,45,56,90,83,114,48,39,26,102};

        displayMarkRange(studentID,examMark,howMany,100,1,"All Students that have valid marks");
        displayMarkRange(studentID,examMark,howMany,100,70,"All Distinction students");
        displayMarkRange(studentID,examMark,howMany,69,55,"All Merit students");
        displayMarkRange(studentID,examMark,howMany,54,40,"All Pass students");
        displayMarkRange(studentID,examMark,howMany,39,1,"All Fail students");
        displayMarkRange(studentID,examMark,howMany,69,40,"All Pass or Merit students");
        displayMarkRange(studentID,examMark,howMany,100,90,"Student that got between 90 and 100");
        displayMarkRange(studentID,examMark,howMany,10,1,"Student that got between 10 and 1");
        displayMarkRange(studentID,examMark,howMany,80,20,"Student that got between 80 and 20");
        displayMarkRange(studentID,examMark,howMany,100,**Averagemark**,"Students that got more than the average");
        displayMarkRange(studentID,examMark,howMany,Averagemark,1,"Students that got less than the average");
        displayMarkRange(studentID,examMark,howMany,120,101,"Students whos marks are invalid");
    }// end of psvm 
}//end of public class
```

when i complie the file:

```
Updating property file: H:\PIJOOP\ProjectSectionEleven\build\built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to H:\PIJOOP\ProjectSectionEleven\build\classes
H:\PIJOOP\ProjectSectionEleven\src\projectsectioneleven\pkgExone.java:42: error: ';' expected
           double total + mark [index];
H:\PIJOOP\ProjectSectionEleven\src\projectsectioneleven\pkgExone.java:42: error: not a statement
           double total + mark [index];
2 errors
H:\PIJOOP\ProjectSectionEleven\nbproject\build-impl.xml:628: The following error occurred while executing this line:
H:\PIJOOP\ProjectSectionEleven\nbproject\build-impl.xml:246: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: As you are just starting out, I would recommend a good Java IDE to catch errors such as these before you even compile. Take a look at [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) or [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/). Both will provide solutions to fix these problems.

Answer (score 3):

This is not valid code

```
double total + mark [index];
```

perhaps you intended

```
total += mark [index];
```

You only declare a variable once for a given scope.

Instead of

```
    **double calculatedaverage = total/validentires;**
    return calculatedaverage;
```

I would just

```
return total / validentires;
```

---

For your interest, this is how I might have written the method.  Note: the `size` must be an `int` not a double.

```
static double average(double... marks) {
    double total = 0;
    int count= 0;

    for(double mark: marks) {
        if (mark < 1 || mark > 100) continue;

        total += mark;
        count++;
    }
    return total / count;
}
```

You can call this for all marks

```
double average = average(marks);
```

or for some marks

```
double average = average(Arrays.copy(marks, size)); // note size must be an int.
```

Comment: double total + mark [index]; <- in terms of this it tells me it is already defined as calaverage(double[],double) ";" expected but i already have the ; in there?  i have the same problem with int validentries=validentries +1, already defined in calaverage, vairable not intialized. I dropped the calculated average part in favour of the suggestions posted

Comment: @PatrickVonOhsen Remove the `int` in front of `int validentries= validentries +1;`. You only need to specify the type of the variable once, when you declare the variable, as Peter said.

Answer (score 0):

`double total + mark [index]` is syntactic nonsense. You probably meant `total += mark[index]` since you have already declared `double total`.

A similar argument applies to your second error: you are redeclaring `calculatedaverage`. Here you just want to drop `double`.

I would suggest, though, to drop the whole variable `calculatedaverage` and simply write `return total/validentires;`

Answer (score 0):

As it says have a look @ this line `**double total + mark [index];`. Shouldnt it be `total += mark[Index];` ?

Look carefully at the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not syntactically valid:

```
       double total + mark [index];
```

I am guessing that you meant to say:

```
       total += mark [index];
```

The next line also has a problem:

```
       int validentries= validentries +1;
```

While syntactically valid, it hides the other `validentries` instead of updating it. Use:

```
       validentries= validentries +1;
```

Lastly, you have `calculatedaverage` declared twice. You can remove the declaration that appears at the top of your function:

```
    double calculatedaverage;
```